# How to access object dynamically with event.target.name in react typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, forms, input, setstate

When accessing the object dynamically using **event.target.name** I get an error like the following:

```
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'Partial<Lines>'.
  No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'Partial<Lines>'.ts(7053)
```

My code now:

```
type Lines = {
  product_id: string | number;
  product_name: string;
  quantity: number;
  unit_of_measure: string;
}
```

```
type Transfer = {
  type: string;
  from_name: string;
  from_id: string | number;
  to_name: string;
  to_id: string | number;
  lines: Partial<Lines>[];
}
```

```
const [transfer, setTransfer] = useState<Transfer>({  
    type: 'option', from_name: '', to_name: '', from_id: '', to_id: '', 
    lines: [{ product_id: '', product_name: "", quantity: 0, unit_of_measure: "" }]
  });
```

```
const handleInputChange = (index: number, event: { target: HTMLInputElement }) => {
    const values = [...transfer.lines];
    values[index][event.target.name] = event.target.value; //the error is here
    
    setTransfer((prevLine) => {
      return {...prevLine, lines: values}
    });
};
```

When accessing using this code is still an error, what is the right way to access it? Thanks.

`values[index][event.target.name] = event.target.value;`

Answer (score 1):

Solved, I changed this code

```
const key = event.target.name;
```

to use [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions)

```
const key = event.target.name as keyof Lines;
```